# The election message and edited question message is not available in the Inbox on the iOS app

Tags: bug, moderator-election, ios-app, global-inbox

If there is a message, like for the election in the iOS app, there will be a Count for "Recent inbox messages". But if I tap on it, there is no message shown.

Is it a bug?

**UPDATE**

Same issue i can see with the edit question message

Comment: I got an inbox. (in desktop version). Assume it is a bug with iOS app

Comment: @SagarV Yes in browser version i have also the message. But not in the app

Comment: Probably an unhandled inbox item type.